# How can I hide series from a HighCharts legend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have 4 series in my chart. 2 are visible when the chart loads. 2 are hidden.

When the user zooms in, the visibility switches.

How can I have a legend that only displays the 2 visible series?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Pass `showInLegend` parameter to series you don't want to be visible in legend like:

```
series.showInLegend = false;
```

Comment: Can you then show it in the tooltip (this removes that).

Comment: @jdborg You would neet to write the formatter yourself and look it up directly from the series data