# Update legend to include only series visible after zoom in on range

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I want to have my legend update to only show the series that are visible after I zoom in on a range.

The following seems to tell me which property on the series to set.

[How can I hide series from a HighCharts legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781110/how-can-i-hide-series-from-a-highcharts-legend)

The question is how do I determine which series are visible in the range I've zoomed in on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `series.points.length` - if will be equal 0, that should means there is no visible plotted points.

Comment: I've tried using both events (selection and redraw) and when I test for series.points.length it always gives the entire series length rather than the visible points.

Comment: I see.. In that case - you need to loop through all that points and compare each points `x` with extremes from sleection event (I think afterSetExtremes is a little better).

Comment: As you suggested I ended up looping through each series and each point checking to see if x was in the new min-max resized range.